# How grab filename from url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I write simple script for my VIP user by PHP. now I need to change many (+4000) links format to compilable with my script.

I need grab file name from url's.

URL e.x `dw.example.com/download.php?d=blabla/blabla/2014/test.zip`

URL e.x `dw.example.com/download.php?d=blabla/blabla/test.zip`

The big problem is the files are not in the same path (directory), I try to use .htaccess to rewrite url's to something like `dw.example.com/download.php?d=blabla/blabla&f=test.zip`
But it's not work.

Is there any way for resolve the problem by .htaccsess? if not, how can I get the file name from this url type:

URL e.x `dw.example.com/download.php?d=blabla/blabla/2014/test.zip`

Comment: `pathinfo()` will do it

Comment: if by filename you mean "test.zip" you can use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) , `array_pop(explode('/',$url))` should give you test.zip for all your examples.

Comment: as for RewriteRule the following should work (untested) `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} d=(.*)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^download\.php download.php?d=%1&f=%2`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} d=(.*)/([^/]+)$ RewriteRule ^download\.php download.php?d=%1&f=%2` it's not work as I need. I'll test others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Bor691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461004/bor691) by `array_pop(explode('/',$url))` can grab the file name.